# Beginner python in the classroom

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I'm new to python and I'm trying to do my labs for class and this one keeps giving me a syntax error. Please help out if possible.

````
import random
name = input("Please enter your name")
print(name)
integ = int(input(name + ","  +  " please enter an integer: "))
print(integ)
integ2 = int(input(name + "," + " please enter another integer: "))
print(integ2)
divis = (integ % integ2)
print(divis)
if divis == 0:
    print(str(integ) + " is divisible by " + (str(integ2))
else:
    print(str(integ) + " is NOT divisible by " + (str(integ2))```
````

Comment: Where is the syntax error?  What exactly is the text of the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your brackets are not balanced.

```py
import random
name = input("Please enter your name")
print(name)
integ = int(input(name + ","  +  " please enter an integer: "))
print(integ)
integ2 = int(input(name + "," + " please enter another integer: "))
print(integ2)
divis = (integ % integ2)
print(divis)
if divis == 0:
    print(str(integ) + " is divisible by " + (str(integ2)))
else:
    print(str(integ) + " is NOT divisible by " + (str(integ2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last 2 print statements are missing a closing ')'

```
import random
name = input("Please enter your name")
print(name)
integ = int(input(name + ","  +  " please enter an integer: "))
print(integ)
integ2 = int(input(name + "," + " please enter another integer: "))
print(integ2)
divis = (integ % integ2)
print(divis)
if divis == 0:
    print(str(integ) + " is divisible by " + (str(integ2)))
else:
    print(str(integ) + " is NOT divisible by " + (str(integ2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to close the brackets. It should be like this:

```
import random
name = input("Please enter your name")
print(name)
integ = int(input(name + ","  +  " please enter an integer: "))
print(integ)
integ2 = int(input(name + "," + " please enter another integer: "))
print(integ2)
divis = (integ % integ2)
print(divis)
if divis == 0:
    print(str(integ) + " is divisible by " + (str(integ2)))
else:
    print(str(integ) + " is NOT divisible by " + (str(integ2)))
```